# How to get rid of "DataReader associated with this Command" on deployment environment

Tags: c#, datatable, sqldataadapter

I tried searching answers associated with this problem here and all of them works in the test enviroment but not in deployment.

I have this function that works well on test environment:

```
    static SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.73;Initial Catalog=CAMFIN;Integrated Security=False;User ID=user;Password=password;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False");


    private static void CreateTable(string query, string filename, string subject, string reportref, string branch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Preparing data....");
        if (dbconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            dbconn.Open();
        }

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dbconn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Today);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branch", branch);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt); //throws an error on production


            if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
            {
                string attachments = filedir + filename + ".xlsx";
                DatatableToExcel(dt, attachments, subject, filename);
                filestosend.Add(attachments);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(branchname + " Office has no data to bound.");
            }
        }
    }
```

When I test it on production, the function throws and error.

```
Error:
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

Comment: I too had this kind of an error and all I did was use a try catch statement to avoid seeing the error and then exception that often arose from the error I logged it. That way my runs without any glitch